# Using runtime types with linq

Tags: c#, linq, generics, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm using [Readify Neo4jClient](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient) to make cypher-queries to a neo4j graph-database.

At some point I want to make a query to the database like this:

```
var results = Client.Cypher
                 .Match("(entity:" + myEntityType1 + ") -[:" + myRelationshipType + "]- (entity2:" + myEntityType2 + ")")
                 .Where((Entity entity) => entity.Id == pEntity.Id)
                 .Return(entity2 => entity2.As<runtimeType>())
                 .Results;
```

At compile time I don't have information on the type that will be loaded by the query. The type I want to load from the db is only known on runtime. Is there a way I can make the linq expression (given to the Return()-function) take a runtime type instead of a hard coded type?

The runtime type will be given by a PropertyInfo object.

### Edit

I'm sorry. I missed out some important information:

The runtime type will be a type that inherits from a type that is known on compile time. 
Giving that known type to the linq expression will give me an result. But of course, this result will only contain the fields declared in the inherited type.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is basically, no, for a very simple reason, "What are you going to do with it next?"

Eventually, you will have to store in in a compile-time typed variable (meaning you really know what the type is, you just don't realize it), or you will have to store it in a `System.Object` for much of it's lifetime anyway, so you might as will start now.

Comment: or dynamic.... which is still `System.Object` I suppose.... and I've always felt like not using strong typing in C# is just a bad idea.

Comment: I'm trying to put as much logic in the base class as possible. Otherwise i'll have to implement the same logic in each of my inherited classes. The only difference between this logic would be the classes fields that are saved to or filled by the database. Everytime I see a certain pattern that is implemented in different classes, I like to check if there is a way to provide this logic in a generic manner.